# Duplicate fields because of my SQL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

```
IF ({PICT_Picture.Job_Print} = TRUE) THEN 
    IF({PICT_Picture.Process_Name}=["SMALL MOULDING","LARGE MOULDING"]) THEN 
         "YES" 
    ELSE
         "NO"
ELSE 
    "NO"
```

`PICT_Picture.Job_Print` - is a tick box that allows me to print a picture on a production route card.

`PICT_Picture.Process_Name` - is a drop down box that allows me to select what process a picture is for.

The problem I am having is if I have multiple images attached to a product that is on a generated report, duplicated rows will be created for each picture I have attached regardless of being under `LARGE MOULDING`, `SMALL MOULDING`, `INSPECTION`, etc.

I have very little knowledge about crystal reports and SQL, I am looking for a line of code that will only generate one line per product regardless of how many pictures are attached.

If you require any additional information please say and I will try and attach it as soon as possible.

Thanks

~EDIT

> {ORDE_Goods.Job_Number}=previous({ORDE_Goods.Job_Number})

I put this in suppress no drill-down, It worked right away.

It got rid of all of the duplicate jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this in Crystal reports is to create a group. Group on your "primary key" then move all your fields from the details section of the report canvas into the group footer section and suppress the details section. Further explanation:

Before- duplicating records:

[image]

After (detail section suppressed, group added on order number- we want 1 record per order number):

[image]

L

Comment: I will need some further explanation, in layman's terms please.

Comment: i've edited to add a few screenshots that should help explain

Answer (score -1):

If you're executing `SELECT` query can you not add `DISTINCT` to select one line per product.

For example,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product, ... FROM YourTable
```